# Didn't earn the curious badge

Tags: bug, badges

I got a system message that I earned the curious badge. But actually I did not.

[image: screenshot]

Looking at the badge list in my profile shows the same. I did not get it.

Comment: This was [already reported on Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262306/notification-that-i-have-earned-curious-badge-but-not-earned-in-reality), where it belongs because the bug only affects Stack Overflow.

Comment: Another use experienced the same this very moment: [curious-about-curious-badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/234970/)

Answer (score 2):

StackOverflow has sent out the announcements, but not awarded the badges yet. There's a [question about it on the meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262306/notification-that-i-have-earned-curious-badge-but-not-earned-in-reality) but we have not yet been told if this is a bug or not (it sounds like it is though).