# Curious about curious badge

Tags: discussion, badges

I recently awarded with curious badge.

I get a notification like:

[image: Curious]

But when I checked my badges list, it is not there.

[image: Badges]

1. Is that a bug ?
2. Can someone explain little bit about the criteria for achieving `Curious`, `Inquisitive` and `Socratic` badges ?